# Oracle What is the difference between / and sys?

Tags: oracle

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
sqlplus sys as sysdba
```

Are there any difference between / and sys?

Comment: Visit https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2297139

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is now no difference in `/ AS SYSDBA` and `SYS AS SYSDBA`.

[Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com) specifically stipulates this in [this thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:61866277480450).

Basically he explains that the SYSDBA suffix effectively connects you to the database as SYS no matter what credentials you give, the example he uses is:

> connect santa/claus as sysdba
>
> same as
>
> connect / as sysdba

connect santa/claus as sysdba

```
sys%ORA10GR2> connect santa/claus as sysdba
Connected.
sys%ORA10GR2> show user
USER is "SYS"
```

Hope it helps...

P.S. This was not the case in 8i and earlier but hopefully you are using a database and SQL*Plus from this century. :-)